# super-keyword in Java giving compile-error

Tags: java

```
class That {
    protected String nm() {
        return "That";
    }
}

class More extends That {
    protected String nm() {
        return "More";
    }

    protected void printNM() {
        That sref = super;

        System.out.println("this.nm() = " + this.nm());
        System.out.println("sref.nm() = " + sref.nm());
        System.out.println("super.nm() = " + super.nm());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new More().printNM();
    }
}
```

When trying to compile More.java I'm getting 4 errors:

```
More.java:7: error: '.' expected
                That sref = super;
                                 ^
More.java:7: error: ';' expected
                That sref = super;
                                  ^
More.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
                System.out.println("this.nm() = " + this.nm());
                      ^
More.java:9: error: ';' expected
                System.out.println("this.nm() = " + this.nm());
                          ^
4 errors
```

Is something wrong with the code? (It's from the book "The Java Programming Language" p.62)

**EDIT:**
From the book:
"And here is the output of printNM:

```
this.nm() = More
sref.nm() = More
super.nm() = That
```

So either they're using some deprecated super-feature(I think this is the first edition of the book) or it is a typo and maybe they meant:
"That sref = new More()"

Comment: super() instead of super

Comment: @"Kit Ho" No, printNM() is a method, not a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `super` that way. Either use it in a constructor, with brackets - `super()` or `super.method()` (or in generics)

In your case this keyword shouldn't be there. If you want an instance of the super class, just have

```
That sref = new That();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change : `That sref = super;` to `That sref = super();`

This statement is basically trying to get hold of the object reference of the super class type, so you need to call the constructor for it - which is done using `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stated, you can't. You probably could do some hacks through reflection, but side from that you can't do it. You need to know what class you're making your new Object. In this case, you have to make it `new That()`.

Comment: But that code is "straight from the horse's mouth", what did Gosling mean to write?

Comment: You'll have to provide a citation if you want to involve the context of the statement.

Comment: @sadsadasssssa: As far as I can tell, it has been miscopied. This fragment of code is in course notes at Cornell and (judging from the characters) somewhere in Korea and China, without the impossible `super` call. Whether this is in the original book of the OP, I can't guess.